# Which thread is an object's event handling processed in?

Tags: c++, multithreading, events

I have a class created to act as a thread.

In that class, I create an object. This objects has an event which performs a callback to a method created within my thread class.

So then, my main application/GUI thread creates this thread & starts it.

At this point, my main GUI thread sits idle (awaiting keyboard events) & my thread's execute method sits in an infinite loop (waiting for terminate).

Then, the created object detects something, firing an event, which triggers the call-back to the thread classes method.

The question then is, **which thread/process is this method performed in?**
My main application thread (& GUI handler)?
Or the thread I started, which created the object that fired the event/callback?

I'm presuming that the main application thread is interrupted. Is this right?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to say what thread is executing the callback.  The callback may be an APC queued to the thread that created the object, (ie. the 'thread I started'), or a callback directly from a kernel thread or even a thread from another process via. shared memory.  Your main application thread may, or may not, be running at the time of the callback - there is no reason, in general, for any processor core that may be running the main thread to be interrupted because some callback has been executed somewhere by some thread.

Comment: @Martin James He hasn't provided enough information because he's Psychic but forgot that we're not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic here, the event handler simply runs on the same thread as the code that fired the event.  Which is invariably troublesome when you want the event handler to update the UI, that isn't legal to do from any thread other than the one that created the UI objects.

You will have to marshal the call from the worker thread to the UI thread.  That's always supported by whatever class library you use the implement the UI.  You didn't say, it smells like Winforms in which case you use Control::BeginInvoke().  If it is raw Windows then you use PostMessage().  Etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

The callback is executed on the thread that waits for the event and calls the callback. In this case it's your worker thread.

Your main thread (GUI thread) is not interrupted, not counting the interruption by the OS to do a potential context switch.